# Variable field in div via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to "send" a variable to a div a via a javascript that you helped me set up a year or so ago. Basically...

The variable playlist I've got set up comes from:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 var play = '<?php echo "$play"; ?>';
 var playlist = "playlists/" + play + ".xml";
 ***command to send to "var_playlist" ****;
</script>
```

And then needs to get sent to:

```
<!--START - PICKLE PLAYER -->
<div data-media="var_playlist"></div>
<!-- END - PICKLE PLAYER -->
```

Thanks so much for any help!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "send"? Does that "pickle player" have some API, could you link to it? [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? And: Why does it need JavaScript, can't you just set the div up with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('div[data-media]').innerHTML = playlist;
```

Or if you want to change the value of `data-media` attribute you can try:

```
document.querySelector('div[data-media]').dataset.media = playlist;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5tb3N/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/V4aCC/

It's tough to know what you mean by "send".  The linked JSFiddle will place the text contained in a Javascript string into the HTML of the element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to set the `data-media` attribute to the value of `playlist`, you can use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute)

```
mediadiv.setAttribute('data-media', playlist);//where mediadiv is the div in question
```